# common sense advice about python package management on OSX for beginners

Tags: python, installation, package, homebrew, macports

If I'm learning python development on OSX (Snow Leopard), how should I best manage my python packages?

I am very excited about the large number of great python packages out there. I would love to start learning them, but package management has got me totally confused. Clearly I have no idea what I'm doing. I see many questions on Stack Overflow that address package management, and people frequently answer them by saying "Why don't you just use *x*? Look how easy it is in this single line I copied from my shell,"

```
$ x install something
```

Which is a great answer until *x* fails to handle some specific dependencies or can't handle package *y*. Here's what I've already attempted:

1. I started out just installing things with [easy_install](https://web.archive.org/web/20130208091204/http://packages.python.org:80/distribute/easy_install.html).
2. I soon found that some important packages had missing dependencies (PIL)
   so I hunted around and discovered [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).
3. I started using MacPorts and all my environment variables got really confusing, so I learned enough bash to reconfigure `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, and `sys.path` to get things working (and to make my terminal window look sweet). MacPorts seemed great for a while.
4. But then I got confused about which version of different modules I was using, and I found more dependency issues (GDAL) ...
5. Then several very intelligent people strongly recommended I switch to [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
   So I uninstalled MacPorts and installed Homebrew.
6. Now that I have Homebrew, I can't seem to install much of anything, because I don't know how to create [Formula](https://web.archive.org/web/20100419102657/http://github.com:80/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula) for most of the python packages I want to use. If a package is listed at [pypi](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415050937/https://pypi.python.org/pypi), I don't know if I should actually use Homebrew, or just figure out how to configure easy_install to install to Homebrew directories. And I still don't know how I should best approach missing dependencies. Maybe there's some secret repository of python-related Formula? or an easy way of converting [portfiles](https://web.archive.org/web/20200510115520/https://www.macports.org/ports.php) into Formula?

I know that the right answer might depend on what I'm trying to install. I'm trying to install sets of packages that let me:

1. play around and automate everything with python

   - appscript
   - PIL
   - pygame
2. do GIS related work in python

   - gdal
   - shapely
   - postgis
   - scipy
3. explore the wondrous possibilities of web apps

   - django
   - google-app-engine

I'm fully willing to wipe everything off my machine, which must be a bit cluttered with scraps of packages by now. If I should be learning [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/), or just learning more about the basic process of checking dependencies and installing them myself, I'm happy to do that. If I should just dig into Homebrew, I happy to do that as well. How should I deal with these issues, which often prevent me from doing what I really want to do (make neat stuff with python)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to handle python packages is to have a set of Python installations separate from the system Python, one for each version you need.
**This way I do not pollute the main python with old versions of packages, and I can delete them and reinstall them without any of my projects having problems.**

Details:

On OS X, using the Macports versions are fine. The same is probably true for homebrew, although I never used it. (On Linuxes I install Python from source into /opt/pythonxx/, for example /opt/python25/, /opt/python26/, /opt/python27 and /opt/python31.)

I then *never* install any packages into these Pythons, with the exception of `virtualenv`, `distribute` and `pip`, which I install in all of them. When I want to install a package for a project, I make a virtualenv for that project with the python version I use for it:

```
$ cd /home/projects
$ /opt/python27/bin/virtualenv acoolproject
$ cd acoolproject
$ ./bin/pip install ThepackageIneed.
```

As you install each projects dependencies separately, you avoid dependency issues and version conflicts and version confusion.

You can enable and disable environments with virtualenv, I tend never to do that, I use the python executable explicitly instead:

```
$ ./bin/python main.py
```

or

```
$ /home7projects/acoolproject/bin/python
```

If I need things that you can't just install with pip, like Plone, or nginx or varnish, I use zc.buildout to make a replicatable environment configuration, zc.buildout will also run in isolation, so no packages gets installed in the main pythons.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the following strongly. I use them for basic package management.

- virtualenv: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv
- virtualenvwrapper: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper
- yolk: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk
- pip : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Tutorial / blogs that should help:

- http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/
- http://paintincode.blogspot.com/2010/08/install-pip-virtualenv.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Homebrew, you'll probably want to use `pip` to install Python packages. `pip` can be installed via Homebrew, but Homebrew doesn't include formulae for other Python packages. But it's pretty easy to install packages using pip -- as simple as

```
$ pip install <package>
```

(The package name can be found on PyPI.) If you installed pip via Homebrew, that's all you need to do.